# Install playwright from a local directory

Tags: python, playwright

I need to install playwright from a local directory containing archives without check [PyPI]. I'm using the command:

```
py -m pip install --no-index --find-links=MY/PATH playwright-1.27.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl
```

And I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement greenlet==1.1.3 (from playwright) (from versions: 2.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for greenlet==1.1.3
```

I'm trying to find greenlet==1.1.3 for win_amd64 on PyPI for Python 3.11, but there is no such version there.

Is there any other option to install the playwright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/1622 :

> Sounds like we need to upgrade to Greenlet v2 for that.